# First order, parallel reaction integration

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

I have parallel equations: 
\begin{align}\ce{A &->[k_b] B},&\ce{A &->[k_c] C}.\end{align}
I understand how to determine formation of $\ce{A}$ (with the integration) but I really keep going in circles with integrating $\ce{B}$. If I can have some assistance in how to integrate $\ce{B}$, then I will be fine for integrating $\ce{C}$.

This is what I have:
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}[\ce{B}]}{\mathrm{d}t} 
&= k_b[\ce{A_0}] \cdot \mathrm{e}^{(-k_b+k_c)t}\\
\int_{[\ce{A_0}]}^{[\ce{A}]}\frac{\mathrm{d}[B]}{\mathrm{d}t} 
&= \int k_b\cdot[A] \mathrm{d}t\\
\ln\frac{[\ce{B}]}{[\ce{A_0}]} 
&= \int k_b\cdot[\ce{A_0}] \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-(k_b+k_c)\cdot t}\mathrm{d}t\\
\end{align}

To save the embarrassment, once I raise to the "$\mathrm{e}$" of both sides, I get 
\begin{align}
\frac{[\ce{B}]}{[\ce{A_0}]} 
&= \mathrm{e}^{\frac{k_b\cdot[\ce{A_0}]}{(k_b+k_c)}t} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^ {-(k_b+k_c)t}}\\
[\ce{B}] &=[\ce{A_0}] \mathrm{e}^{\frac{k_b\cdot[\ce{A_0}]}{k_b+k_c}t} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{e}^{-(k_b+k_c)t}}\\
\end{align}

Can someone show me the steps of integrating the $\int k_b\cdot[\ce{A}] \mathrm{d}t$?
Very basic steps are available in solutions, but it still does not fully show the integration/algebra and I am just very lost.

Comment: I submitted an edit to improve the formatting of your post. Let me know if everything was  rewritten as you intended.

Comment: I have only corrected some of the bad MathJax,  there might still be errors in the constants introduced by @Tyberius, please check again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start by solving the rate equation for $\ce{[A]}$:
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\ce{[A]}}{\mathrm{d}t} 
&= -k_\mathrm{B}\ce{[A]} - k_\mathrm{C}\ce{[A]}&
\Longleftrightarrow&&
\ce{[A]} 
&= \ce{[A]_0}\exp\left(-(k_\mathrm{B}+k_\mathrm{C}\right)t).
\end{align}
We can then solve the rate equation for $\ce{[B]}$:
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}\ce{[B]}}{\mathrm{d}t} &= k_\mathrm{B}\ce{[A]} \\
&= k_\mathrm{B}\ce{[A]_0}\exp\left(-(k_\mathrm{B} + k_\mathrm{C}\right)t)\\
\ce{[B]}-\ce{[B]_0} 
&= \int_{\ce{[B]_0}}^{\ce{[B]}}\mathrm{d}\ce{[B]}' \\
&= k_\mathrm{B}\ce{[A]_0}\int_0^t\mathrm{d}t'\,\exp\left(-(k_\mathrm{B}+k_\mathrm{C}\right)t')\\
 &= \frac{k_\mathrm{B}\ce{[A]_0}}{k_\mathrm{B} + k_\mathrm{C}}[1-\exp\left(-(k_\mathrm{B}+k_\mathrm{C}\right)t)].
\end{align}
I use primes to distinguish the variable of integration from the limits of integration.

Comment: The expression given is not correct, one limit has been missed, I have edited please check

Comment: Just to add, the term in front of the exponential  ($kB/(k_B+k_C)$is the fraction going towards B.

Comment: Thank you @a-cyclohexane-molecule. Can you just lastly explain the [B]}-[B]_o and where that comes from? I know the ln[B]/[A]0 = ln[b] - ln[A]o but if you "e" both sides, I don't see how you get your equation, and then I am back to the original problem so there must be a step I do not know. And in the integration you ended up with a one, but I dont understand how that comes about.

Comment: Sorry about the mistake; thanks for fixing it. @juliodesa, $\ce{[B]}$ and $\ce{[B]_0}$ are the bounds of our integral -- we start with $\ce{[B]_0}$ concentration of species B, and have $\ce{[B]}$ concentration of species B at time $t$. The one comes from evaluating the integral at the lower bound of $t=0$.

Comment: and also note that the rate constant at which B appears is $k_b+k_c$ and similarly for appearance of C and disappearance of A, this is true even though the rate constant to B is $k_b$ and that to C, $k_c$.

Comment: Why is ka=kb+kc? Can you explain this thought to me

Comment: And why did you use primes....I don't understand this logic

Comment: @Abhinav, 1. What do you mean by ka? 2. Primes denote dummy variables of integration.

Comment: By ka ,I mean the rate of dissapearence of reactant A

Comment: I have never heard about dummy variables of integration....I am new to calculus so maybe that's why

Comment: @Abhinav, A yields B with a rate kb and A yields C with a rate kc---in other words A is consumed at a rate kb in forming B and at a rate kc in forming C. Then the overall rate of consumption of A is kb + kc.